# Bootstrap glyphicons aren't appearing when using Rails 5 and bootstrap-sass gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, ruby-on-rails-5

Glyphicons from bootstrap aren't showing up on my site. I went to check the `Network` tab in chrome dev tools and saw requests like this for the fonts:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

So I grab the glyphicon fonts and place them in `app/assets/fonts/bootstrap`, but that doesn't work. I moved the `fonts/` folder to `public/` and tried again. Glyphicons worked, but this just seems like bad practice.

How do I keep the fonts in `app/assets/fonts` and get them to load right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was writing the question, I figured it out.

In your bootstrap theme file, look for these lines:

```
//== Iconography
//
//## Specify custom location and filename of the included Glyphicons icon font. Useful for those including Bootstrap via Bower.

//** Load fonts from this directory.

// [converter] If $bootstrap-sass-asset-helper if used, provide path relative to the assets load path.
// [converter] This is because some asset helpers, such as Sprockets, do not work with file-relative paths.
$icon-font-path: if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, "bootstrap/", "../fonts/bootstrap/");
```

I changed the variable `$icon-font-path` so it looks like this:

```
$icon-font-path: if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, "bootstrap/", "../assets/fonts/bootstrap/");
```

Note: all the glyphicon font files are present in `app/assets/fonts/bootstrap`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use: [font-awesome-sass](https://rubygems.org/gems/font-awesome-sass)

Comment: That's great and all, but I'm using the _glyphicons_ font, and not font awesome.